# how can i keep an image name when changing its extention

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can i get the file name without its root and path. only a name so i can save the images i want to convert with the same original name?

```
import sys
import os,glob
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter


path = os.getcwd()

if not os.path.exists('converted'):
    save_to = os.makedirs('converted')


for i in glob.glob(f'{path}/*.jpg'):

    img = Image.open(i)

    img.save(???????)  ########  <---------?????????

    #i want to save the imege whith its original name,
    # but with a different extention, and i want to save it to a different folder then cwd
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.path.basename` to get filename without path.

Use `os.path.splitext` to split filename into stem and suffix.

Comment: but it gives me the path as well...

Comment: combine those two functions to get filename without path and suffix

Answer (score 0):

Did you wanted something like this?

```
for i in glob.glob(f'{path}/*.png'):
    img = Image.open(i)
    basename = os.path.basename(i)
    root_ext = os.path.splitext(basename)[0]
    ext = ".png"
    img.save(path+"/converted/" + root_ext + ext)
```

Comment: what does 'path' in this line stands for??       img.save(path+"/converted/" + root_ext + ext)

Comment: It's the path from path = os.getcwd().